# Online Sitemap Generators not working, how can I Generate a Sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, xml-parsing, umbraco, xml-sitemap

I have tried various tools online, but no matter what I do, I get around 880 webpages generated from sitemaps online.  I even paid for a service that rendered only 880 webpage urls in a sitemap.xml file.

There are over 1,000 members on this site, and each of the members have a webpage for themselves on the site, so I should get at least 1,000 results.  Why am I only getting approx. 800 - 900 results?

Sites and software that I used for generating an XML file:

- http://gsitecrawler.com/en/download/file/?file=1&mirror=1
- http://www.sitemaps-builder.com/
- https://pro-sitemaps.com/cp/

Google Webmaster Tools is telling me that there are over 2000 urls.  Why can I not find all of these and generate a sitemap from them all?

The site is:  http://www.discoverPHL.com

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iu'm checking your site with internal tools and also online tools and until now i get more issue on several pages as connection timeout and so on. you may take a look here :

[image]

I will complete my check in 20-30 minutes then i will update you with more info and log too if is possible.
Also i confirm that error seems real coz i checked some link from my server in england and from server in USA and both give me issue on related pages.So it could be possibile that there's some wrong stuff.
I will update you soon as possibile.

Hello guy, i'm sorry but i have to go .....you may check by yourself with this free tools (it use java) [Sitemap Generator online free](http://www.auditmypc.com/xml-sitemap.asp)

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this actually helped me create a sitemap!  And I can't believe I paid for tools that didn't even work as nice as this one does!!!  Cheers :)

Comment: more time we paid for bad services